# Using excel attached in an email as a source in SSIS package

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I want to use the excel sheet which comes as an attachment in an email as a source and then I want to export this data into the database table. Although I don't have any restriction on using any third party tool but I would like to avoid that. Any pointers regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you install an email client like Outlook on the SSIS box then you can use automation (i.e. a script task in SSIS) to extract the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything that lets **SSIS** read email, let alone extract attachments and process them as spreadsheets. (BizTalk can, but that's another subject entirely.) It's much easier to have the person receiving the email save the attachment to a predefined location (typically a network share) and then launch an SSIS package to read the spreadsheet and load the database accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is old thread. but i used nsoftware ssis task v4 to read the emails from mail box , download attached csv to specified location. this is ssis component i integrated with my ssis package. made life much easier.. after the file download next process is reading file from location and process and put into database.. 
hope this one help someone in future.